# Can't access textarea and button in form HtmlUnit

Tags: javascript, java, forms, htmlunit

I wrote this code in Java:

```
public void homePage() throws Exception {

    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);
    final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);

    webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);

    HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://zof.interreport.com/diveport#");
    webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(5000);

    System.out.println(page.getForms());
}
```

This program puts out a form with `class="dvp_form"`

So far so good, however I want to access the `login` and `username` textareas and the `log-on` button within this form so I can automatically log in.

I really have no idea how to do this.

Any help would be great.

Comment: You can start your journey here: http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingStarted.html

Comment: I solved the problem! Thanks!

Comment: Fixed some syntax of the question